# Is it possible to do server sent events with Google Cloud endpoints and Kubernetes?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, server-sent-events, google-kubernetes-engine

If so how did you do it?

I have a REST endpoint and would like to initiate a sse communication from a web page.

I did not find any documentation on this and don't know if it is achievable.